# How do I make the alert dialog to display all the items of a listview when it only has a few items?

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, dialog

I have created a dialog and got a problem that only part of the items in the list can be displayed in the layout. The others can only be seen after scrolling the listview and the below images are the effect when the dialog is shown.

The dialog is an alert dialog, and I create it by using the alert.builder, and the layout of this  is `LinearLayout`. Any ideas?

Comment: where is the image you mentioned above?

Comment: can you please post the effort/code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another class that extends dialog and overrides the method `onstart()`. There you can do your stuff....and this is not affected your main activity.

Comment: Hello Keyser,thank you very much,I may try your suggestion later,but what I wonder most is How it happened,and  weather it is possible to solve the problem in just the alert dialog. as it may make things much more complex by creating new class ,because  I have to deal with all kinds of dialog.